# Phonegap and mobile commerce

Tags: cordova

How are transactions handled in phonegap apps?
Is everything self contained in the app? if so, how does it carry out credit card transactions? i assume you will need an active net connection to carry out payments, or when the users clicks on "Checkout", does it load a page on the users site? I have to implememnt an ecommere element into a jquerymobile app for my boss and not sure where to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A phonegap app is simply a special *web site* that is rendered by an embedded web browser (webview & co) to behave as an app.

From a regular usage (aka on PC) you can think of it as: the Ecommerce system is the website, and your mobile phone app is the browser.

if you input your credit card data into the app it will simply connect to the Ecommerce and submit the information. The Ecommerce will perform the sale transaction and return an outcome. That's how it has to be anyway.

Comment: How do you implement an ecommerce gateway from within the app, e.g. a web site would either load a payment capture page on the gateways site or carry out the transaction through an api. How does it work in apps?

Comment: I would create an API on the server side. Then simply call it... either simply post data to a remote page (like $_POST stuff in php) or create a web service for that matter... the design is really up to you.

Comment: see the thing is you will have the VIEW (html and css crap) on YOUR app and the business logic (transactions, items management, basket management...etc) on server side.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Do we need to take care of transmitting card details from the app to the server? If so, how do you go about securing such details? is submitting to a https server enough?

Comment: Well if you judge it being enough then it is enough. See if you query an https page using a browser you have the same security level as if you trigger an ajax query targeting that same https page.